# AWS Lambda Payloads

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I searched on AWS Lambda documentation but couldn't find an answer to my problem.

Is there a way I can access the entire request body from a Lambda function (written in node.js)?

The `event` parameter only seems to contain parsed JSON properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request body needs to be in XML or JSON in order to be able to access it in your `Lambda` function. You need to specify how it's processed/mapped and passed through in `Integration Request` section of the `API Gateway` dashboard.

Comment: Could you customize the request parameters without using API Gateway?

Comment: How would you execute the Lambda function?

Comment: Scheduling inside AWS CloudWatch

Comment: You can't customize parameters in the CloudWatch event.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the request body in AWS Lambda once you expose it in a Body Mapping Template.

1. Open up your method in API Gateway console
2. Open `Integration Request`
3. In `Integration Request`, open the `Body Mapping Templates` panel
4. Add a `Content Type` of `application/json`
5. Click on your freshly created `application/json` item
6. Add the following template:

```
 {
   "body" : $input.json('$')
 }
```

After that you can access the request body as `event.body` in your Node.js Lambda Function.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might consider setting up lambda as a simple proxy if it works better for your use case. I've found more people using this technique recently.

[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource)

A request like the following:

```
POST /testStage/hello/world?name=me HTTP/1.1
Host: gy415nuibc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
headerName: headerValue

{
    "a": 1
}
```

Will wind up sending the following event data to your AWS Lambda function:

```
{
  "message": "Hello me!",
  "input": {
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/hello/world",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
      "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
      "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
      "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "headerName": "headerValue",
      "Host": "gy415nuibc.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
      "Postman-Token": "9f583ef0-ed83-4a38-aef3-eb9ce3f7a57f",
      "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/2.4.5",
      "Via": "1.1 d98420743a69852491bbdea73f7680bd.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
      "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "pn-PWIJc6thYnZm5P0NMgOUglL1DYtl0gdeJky8tqsg8iS_sgsKD1A==",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "54.240.196.186, 54.182.214.83",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {
      "name": "me"
    },
    "pathParameters": {
      "proxy": "hello/world"
    },
    "stageVariables": {
      "stageVariableName": "stageVariableValue"
    },
    "requestContext": {
      "accountId": "12345678912",
      "resourceId": "roq9wj",
      "stage": "testStage",
      "requestId": "deef4878-7910-11e6-8f14-25afc3e9ae33",
      "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
        "accountId": null,
        "cognitoIdentityId": null,
        "caller": null,
        "apiKey": null,
        "sourceIp": "192.168.196.186",
        "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
        "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
        "userArn": null,
        "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/2.4.5",
        "user": null
      },
      "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "apiId": "gy415nuibc"
    },
    "body": "{\r\n\t\"a\": 1\r\n}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
}
```

Now you have access to all headers, url params, body etc. in each request.